MAUI Blazor Hybrid Specified RuntimeIdentifier is not recognized on Class Library Projects
Whenever I use the following steps to publish my MAUI Blazor Hybrid project, I get an error.
Steps to reproduce:

Build -> Publish
Sideloading as distribution method



Signing method: self signed:


Release configuration:




Target runtime: win10-x64



I hit Create

Error:
Whatever I try I get an error The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-x64' is not recognized. See https://aka.ms/netsdk1083 for more information.. Whenever I select runtime win10-x86, I get the same error but other runtime identifier.
Microsoft link in error:
The link to Microsoft website shows I need to use win-x64 as runtime identifier, but I do not have that one as option in my dropdown. I searched on Google and StackOverflow, also without any luck.
I also tried:

dotnet workload update
dotnet workload install maui
I searched the Microsoft website for updates on Visual Studio, SDK's or .net runtimes. I tried to install/update some, but also without any luck. Maybe I installed the wrong SDK?

Anyone who knows how to solve this issue?
Update 30-04:
I found out that this error only shows when I add project reference to my Blazor MAUI project refering to my Class Library project. How to define this runtime identifier to my Class Library project?

I found out that this error only shows when I add project reference to my Blazor MAUI project refering to my Class Library project. How to define this runtime identifier to my Class Library project?

See this case: NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier "win10-x64" is not recognized and this?

@JianweiSun-MSFT I found those posts earlier, but they did not fix my problem. And also, win-x64 is not an option when I select a target runtime in step 5

Adding <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> to your class library project .csproj is not solving this?

I managed to resolve this issue and get a Blazor Maui Hybrid working with both a referenced RCL and a normal Class Library (but only targeting windows). These were the changes:
In Blazor Maui project changed the TargetFrameworks to TargetFramework


<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>



In my Class Library projects changed what was just targeting Net8.0 to target multiple frameworks:


  <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>



Note I still had to jump through hoops to get it to work, because although this worked on a new clean small project, when I applied to my existing project the Publish option was ghosted.  So, I had to migrate my existing project into a new clean Blazor Maui project a bit at a time checking that the publish didn't break with each change. Make the project references first to check it works. I now have quite a complex Blazor Maui project up and running and I am finally able to publish. It seems a bit flakey.
